# Can I dualboot windows and ubuntu with MBR and GPT?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, uefi

I don't know much about Operating Systems, so I need a little help here.
I have 3 storage drives:

1. For data - The 1TB one
2. Where I have Ubuntu installed - The Sandisk one
3. Where I have windows 10 installed - The samsung one

Previously I had Linux Mint where Ubuntu is now, and dualboot worked fine. But when I installed Ubuntu, now grub doesnt find windows and can't boot windows no more.

I think the problem might be Windows is MBR and Ubuntu is GPT, is it?

**Simplified problem**: Grub doesn't find windows

**Goal:** Be capable of booting windows and ubuntu (now I am only being capable of booting ubuntu)

**More info about my disks:**

*sudo parted -l:*

```
Model: ATA ST1000DM003-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags


Model: ATA SanDisk SSD PLUS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   240GB  240GB  ext4


Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  250GB  250GB  primary  ntfs         boot, esp
 2      250GB   250GB  506MB  primary  ntfs         diag
```

*sudo update-grub:*

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-10-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-10-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

If you need more info pls tell me and I'll do my best. Thank you so much in advanced

Comment: your assumption about MBR GPT is wrong as you mentioned in question. MBR or GPT is the partitioning scheme for a single DISK. if you have one ssd, it can be partitioned either MBR or GPT.. if you have two ssds, Both Can be MBR or GPT or one is MBR and other is GPT

Comment: The Windows install is legacy, and Ubuntu is UEFI, so grub in UEFI cannot boot (or even see ) legacy Windows.  Since they are on separate disks though, booting either disk may be allowed on some machines that give you a preference of legacy/UEFI mode to boot when both are present )

Comment: @ubfan1 sounds reasonable, any idea on why it worked with linux mint?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to install where? Here's what I understand:
You have two SSDs, one which you would like to install Ubuntu on, and one with Windows on it. You also have a 1TB HDD which you want to use as storage for data for both Windows and Ubuntu?
Is this correct?

Comment: I have ubuntu already installed, my problem is that I cant boot windows no more.
(before ubuntu I had linux mint dualboot with my windows)
Will edit question to clarify it!

Comment: Hmm. It's not really a dual-boot if you have Windows on one drive and Linux on the other, but problems with the GRUB boot loader can still arise. I'll look into it and tell you if I find a solution. I don't have much experience with dual-booting Windows, but I will try some stuff in VirtualBox and see if I can find a solution.

Comment: Oh I didnt know. In this case is there a name to refer the "dual-booting"?  Thanks! :)

Comment: It is a dual boot, because  if you boot from a BIOS menu you should see both systems/disks as options, regardless of which disk an OS is installed on. Your issue is that you probably are using  a UEFI BIOS with `sdc` formatted as MBR. That will not work for Windows.

Comment: @PaulBenson and why when I had installed mint along with windows it worked?

Comment: I don't know without a lot more information. Have you tried yet bringing up your BIOS/UEFI menu as I hinted? Is Windows seen as an option there?

Comment: @PaulBenson it shows the storage where windows is installed, but when I try to boot it tells me there is no OS and shows grub rescue :/

Comment: I don't know what your your partitions looked like with Mint, but here it shows an MBR disk, sdc which you say has Windows running (probably) on a UEFI state BIOS. Furthermore the boot partition shows as an esp boot which is [incompatible with Windows on an MBR disk](https://kb.stonegroup.co.uk/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=624).